# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] - Angular ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm using ng-include to attach some HTML pages to one HTML page in AngularJS.

Find the Main.html page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Test">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href ="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="userController">

<div class="container">
  <div ng-include="'test1.htm'"></div>
  <div ng-include="'test2.htm'"></div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

test1.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Full Name: 
</body>
</html>
```

Seems like nothing wrong in my code. But when I load it in browser nothing is displayed and I get console error says,

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=Test&p1=Error%3A%2…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: I get the same issue for this as well.http://plnkr.co/edit/Wf7POLXpqbrmyiRbOlsg?p=preview

Comment: your demo works fine for me , tried in 2 browsers

Comment: paste the error in the browser and check the error...

Comment: Demo works, but if I download the code to my local machine and run, then it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is here

```
<html ng-app="Test">
```

you have to define a new module to use it as app

something Like that

MainModule.js

```
    var app =angular.module("myApp",[]);
    app.controller("myCTRL"["$scope",function($scope){

    }]);
```

then include that js file into your project to use it
Like that

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href ="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>    
            <script src="assets/js/MainModule.js"></script>
</head>

    <body ng-controller="myCTRL">

    <div class="container">
      <div ng-include="'test1.htm'"></div>
      <div ng-include="'test2.htm'"></div>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to include the 'angular route java script file in head tag.
Like this,

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.route.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: No luck..Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
    at Error (native)

Comment: Your plunker code is working in IE 11 check what is the exact error in other browser.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=%24templateRequestProvider%20%3C-%20%24templateRequest%20%3C-%20%24route%20%3C-%20ngViewDirective
   at Anonymous function (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js:36:196)

Comment: the app itself is not defined, no route service used